# Display problems??? Very jarring stretch effect when maximized

Tags: workflow, error

[image: This only happens when it's maximized. I "restore down" then it looks fine. I maximize the window, it appears again.]

SO, what is this? I get this every time I maximize the blender window. It disappears when I "restore down" the window, but I don't like having to do that for the entire time I have to work on it. So how do I fix it? I really want to always have the window maximize, and this is just terrible to look at.

Comment: Possibly a hardware/driver problem. Intel GPU, I assume. Hard to tell without knowing anything about your hardware. Please read [this](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2620/could-we-brush-up-the-help-center-please) to learn how you could help us to give good answers.

Comment: This is an issue with your graphics driver. Updating the graphics driver will most likely fix the issue. See [T75683](https://developer.blender.org/T75683) for a similar report on the bug tracker.